# Generate random ints, which equal 100

Tags: c#

I would like to generate three random ints, which together equal 100. Please help.

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int equal = 100;
a = rnd.Next(1, equal);
b = rnd.Next(1, equal) - a;
c = textvar - a - b;
if(equal == a + b + c) {
Console.Write("Work");
}
```

Comment: Should it be `b = rnd.Next(1, equal-a) ;`?

Comment: Thanks, now it is working.

Comment: Generate two random ints `a` and `b` and set the third int to `100 - a - b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `b = rnd.Next(1, equal) - a;` to `b = rnd.Next(1, equal-a);`
Because in the first case `b` can be less then zero.

Comment: Why negative b is a problem?